# Serializable AjaxRequestTarget

Tags: java, wicket, serializable

As a part of my development in Java using wicket as my web framework , at some point , which it's not necessary to explain why , but right now I need a Serializable version of AjaxRequestTarget. I tried to extend it and add Serializable behavior to it but since AjaxRequestTarget is abstract, I can not extend it. the code bellow somehow shows what I need :

```
public class SerializableART extends AjaxRequestTarget implemets Serializable {

}
```

is there any alternative way of doing this ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this ? You should not keep a reference to AjaxRequestTarget in your page (components, models & behaviors). You cannot use it in a following request.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to ask a XY-problem. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Please read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It make no sense to serialize the AjaxRequestTarget. It is a object which only make sense in the context of a request, so it shouldn't keeped longer then the request.

If you need AjaxRequestTarget somewhere where it is not directly accessible you can access it with `RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)`. But i recommend to pass it as method argument where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make AjaxRequestTarget serializable, this is similar to HttpServletRequest:

See this question:

[How Serialize HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410172/how-serialize-httpservletrequest-httpservletresponse)

Answer (score 0):

you must add an extra argument to your panel contractor and pass your parent panel markup to this panel and use this as target markup.

Comment: This is just one option. I prevent using the Wicket-event system for much looser coupling of Components.

Comment: Uh I meant 'prefer' instead of 'prevent'